# how to add fade in and fade out function to play on hover function?

Tags: jquery, audio, fadein, fadeout

I have the following code that activates the sound upon hovering on an object, but would like to add simple fade in and fade out effects (fading in on hovering in and fade out on hovering out). Will be glad for hints.

```
function PlaySound(soundobj) {
var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
thissound.play()}

function StopSound(soundobj) {
var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
thissound.pause();
thissound.currentTime = 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this.

It still does not seem to work. I corrected a few things ad tried this first:

```
 function PlaySound(soundobj) {
var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);

/* putting sound on hold and setting volume to 0 */
thissound.pause().prop("volume", 0);

/* on mouse hover event, play sound and fade in the volume in 1s */
thissound.mouseover(function() {
    thissound.play().animate({volume: 1}, 1000);
});}

function StopSound(soundobj) {
var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);

/* on mouse out event, fade out the volume in 1s */
thissound.mouseout(function() {
    thissound.animate({volume: 0}, 1000)}
});
thissound.pause();
thissound.currentTime = 0;
}
```

My questions would be,
shall the initial volume setting be separated from the function PlaySound?
should the line in mouseout function read: `thissound.play().animate({volume: 0}, 1000)}`

Thanks